# What is happening in "The Crawling Chaos"?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, cthulhu-mythos

I read the short story from H. P. Lovecraft "The Crawling Chaos"

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Crawling_Chaos

At first it's kind of understandable, a guy takes Opiates and gets high, but after that there is a cascade of weird words and i absolutely do not understand anything what is happening anymore.

And i thought i'm good at reading/speaking the english language...

Can you summarise what is happening?

Comment: Summaries of stories are a bit too broad. But basically, the protagonist takes opium and sees blasphemous truths beyond the understanding of humanity, and cyclopean abominations from the far stars. The whole thing is an opium-induced vision of the cosmic horror of existence.

Comment: @Adamant - So, kind of like "Celebrity Strictly Come Dancing", but slightly more understandable and coherent?

Comment: @Adamant As i understand it, Opium guy meets some angelic beings and flyes up with them, looks back after being told to not look back, and sees the self devouring world and gets stuck in space.... Eh, Drugs are Bad :P Is that about right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say he is entering the Astral Plane and is describing the seven rays which create the seven suns at the highest point of reality.

He then meets a spirit guide (Faun in this case, they help travelers through the wilderness). The Faun takes him higher than the source, like above the sky father. So he see's his reality from above (people have called this the mother goddess etc).

This is clearly about his wife's relationship to famous magician known only to all as 'The beast', where they had a love triangle going on. He references him several times an they would of done allot of opium together, so this is like him crawling back into that past life.

Comment: From where do the seven Rays come now? In the third paragraph, do you mean HPL with "he" there?

Comment: The 7 rays or 7 flames, is common in Greek, Vedic, Ayran and later Christian myth. The 7 rays or flames became 7 stars or suns. Common in allot of fantasy, I seen it in Pratchet and Tolkien works too.

There are several wiki articles you can google 'seven rays'. Maybe even do an imagine search you will see psychedelic art with pretty much what is happening in this short story. 

It might be a reference to the Rainbow and the Spectrum of Light.

He - Lovecraft, sorry.

Comment: I doubt it's about a love triangle. Sex, and money are never mentioned in Lovecraft's works. Lovecraft claimed that everything about sex could be observed in a farm, looking at a cow (letter to Belknap Long.) In his novels, he was "emphasizing the qualities proper to him [man] and without stupidly dwelling on those bestial qualities which he has in common with the first pig or goat to come along.”"